# String format doesn’t show int number 1

Tags: python, string, methods, format

I have this method that receives seconds (as an integer) and returns a string with the years, days, hours, minutes and seconds.

When any of the values (years, days, hours, minutes or seconds) = 1 it's not formatted. I have tried to parse to a string but still doesn't work. Does anybody have a clue of what is happening?

```
def seconds_to_text(sec):
    m = sec//60
    h = m//60
    d = h//24
    years = d//365
    days = d - years*365
    hours = h - d*24
    minutes = m - h*60
    seconds = sec % 60
    text = ''
    if years != 0:
        text += f'{years}' + ' years, ' if years > 1 else ' year, '
    if days != 0:
        text += f'{days}' + ' days, ' if days > 1 else ' day,'
    if hours != 0:
        text += f'{hours}' + ' hours, ' if  hours > 1 else ' hour, '
    if minutes !=0:
        text += f'{minutes}' + ' minutes ' if minutes > 1 else ' minute '
    if seconds != 0:
        text += f'and {seconds}' + ' seconds' if seconds > 1 else ' second'
    return text

print(seconds_to_text(1501011301))
// Output: 47 years, 217 days, 19 hours, 35 minutes  second
```

I have tried with a print(f'and {seconds}') and the output is fine, it shows 1. I have also tried with str(seconds) and it doesn't work either.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Use one long f-string: `text += f"{years} year{'s' if years > 1 else ''}, "`

Answer (score 0):

It's been a problem with putting the `if-statement` between parenthesis

```py
text += f'and {seconds}' + ( ' seconds' if seconds > 1 else ' second')
```